# Why is numpy.power slower for integer exponents?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, types, exponentiation

I chose these numbers randomly, but these results seem to be consistent --- a float exponent is 25%-50% faster than an integer one.  How are these handled differently?

```
In [209]: %timeit -n 100000 -r 100 np.power(3.71242, 7)
100000 loops, best of 100: 3.45 µs per loop

In [210]: %timeit -n 100000 -r 100 np.power(3.71242, 7.0)
100000 loops, best of 100: 1.98 µs per loop
```

Comment: If I had to venture a guess, numpy expects a float but received an int and needed to convert.

Comment: @JeffMercado interesting idea --- but it doesn't quite seem to add up:  "%timeit -n 100000 -r 10 if(type(2) == int): float(2)"
==> "100000 loops, best of 10: 571 ns per loop"

Comment: I suspect that an int exponent causes actual multiplication while a float exponent causes the use of logs.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy logs?

Comment: logs = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: @Paul, thanks.  you're so helpful...  here I thought he meant old, fallen trees.  Woops, did I not post this to forestry.SO?!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`np.power` is a [universal function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) (ufunc). These functions can be used on scalars and arrays which have a variety of different datatypes, but must first check the type of input values so that they can determine which internal loop to use to generate suitable output values.

If the input types do not map to any of the ufunc's predefined loops, the ufunc will try to [cast the input values to suitable types](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-casting) (unless it is told otherwise). This checking and conversion of input values has a performance cost associated with it, explaining the timings observed in the question.

The [`types`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.types.html) attribute of a ufunc shows how input datatypes will map to an output datatype. Below is the list of mappings for `np.power`:

```
>>> np.power.types # 'input input -> output'
['bb->b', 'BB->B', 'hh->h', 'HH->H', 'ii->i', 'II->I', 'll->l', 'LL->L', 'qq->q', 
 'QQ->Q', 'ee->e', 'ff->f', 'dd->d', 'gg->g', 'FF->F', 'DD->D', 'GG->G', 'OO->O']
```

Floating-point numbers belong to character code `'g'`, Python integers belong to `'l'`. A full list of these character codes can be found [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-character-codes).

Note that for this ufunc, the datatypes of the two input values must be the same. There is no mapping for a mix of `float` and `int` input datatypes, for example.

But we can still give `np.power` different datatypes and let it cast the values to appropriate datatypes. For a `float` and an `int`, a `float64` number is returned:

```
>>> np.power(3.71242, 7).dtype
dtype('float64')
```

Above you can see that the only input which maps to the `float64` character code `g` is two other `g` values: `'gg->g'`.

So, behind the scenes, `np.power(3.71242, 7)` took a Python `float` and a Python `int` and had to decide which it could safely recast and to what type. The `int` value was safely promoted to a float type `g`. The ufunc then knew which loop to run and returned another `g` value.

For this reason, not mixing input datatypes results in better performance for `np.power`.